# How to find the optimal processing order?

Tags: haskell, logic, lambda-calculus, logic-programming

I have an interesting question, but I'm not sure exactly how to phrase it...

Consider the lambda calculus. For a given lambda expression, there are several possible reduction orders. But some of these don't terminate, while others do.

In the lambda calculus, it turns out that there is one particular reduction order which is *guaranteed* to always terminate with an irreducible solution if one actually exists. It's called Normal Order.

I've written a simple logic solver. But the trouble is, the order in which it processes the constraints seems to have a huge effect on whether it finds any solutions or not. Basically, I'm wondering whether something like a normal order exists for my logic programming language. (Or wether it's impossible for a mere machine to deterministically solve this problem.)

---

So that's what I'm after. Presumably the answer critically depends on exactly what the "simple logic solver" is. So I will attempt to *briefly* describe it.

My program is closely based on the system of combinators in chapter 9 of *The Fun of Programming* (Jeremy Gibbons & Oege de Moor). The language has the following structure:

- The input to the solver is a single *predicate*. Predicates may involve variables. The output from the solver is zero or more *solutions*. A solution is a set of variable assignments which make the predicate become true.
- Variables hold *expressions*. An expression is an integer, a variable name, or a tuple of subexpressions.
- There is an equality predicate, which compares expressions (not predicates) for equality. It is satisfied if substituting every (bound) variable with its value makes the two expressions identical. (In particular, every variable equals itself, bound or not.) This predicate is solved using unification.
- There are also operators for AND and OR, which work in the obvious way. There is no NOT operator.
- There is an "exists" operator, which essentially creates local variables.
- The facility to define *named predicates* enables recursive looping.

One of the "interesting things" about logic programming is that once you write a named predicate, it typically works fowards *and backwards* (and sometimes even *sideways*). Canonical example: A predicate to concatinate two lists can also be used to split a list into all possible pairs.

But sometimes running a predicate backwards results in an infinite search, unless you rearrange the order of the terms. (E.g., swap the LHS and RHS of an AND or an OR somehwere.) I'm wondering whether there's some automated way to detect the best order to run the predicates in, to ensure prompt termination in all cases where the solution set is exactually finite.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It probably will help if you post a few examples of programs in your language, and show how different reduction strategies lead to different results.

Comment: @n.m. Good idea. I'll try to come up with a minimal example...

Comment: See also [Presburger arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) in case you hadn't seen it before -- validity is decidable, and it allows and, or, not, forall, and induction (though perhaps the induction is not as powerful as the recursion you describe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relevant paper, I think: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~shaulm/papers/abstracts/Ledeniov-1998-DCS.html

Also take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_logic_programming#Bottom-up_evaluation

Comment: +1 for a very interesting and relevant-looking paper. I don't know yet whether it answers my question; I guess I'll know _that_ by the time I finish reading it. ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure this 100% answers my _exact_ question, but it's a very interesting read, and a good starting point, so I'm going to accept this answer.